# How to Use Timers in Windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

What are the various ways that a timer can be set up using the Windows API. What are the pros and cons of each method?

I'm using MS DevStudio's C++.

Comment: @subbu: If you really want to get help here on SO you might want to read this carefully: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.

Your questions are so broad that it is hard to understand what you are trying to do. So obviously helping you is not very easy.

Comment: Your question sounds more like a demand "so make any sample code compatible with that". Be polite and the 50,000+ folks here will be nice to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method for handling timers is to use waitable timer objects. These don't require any message processing, don't use WM_TIMER or callbacks. As such, they're a bit more complex. Understanding the Windows event system will be helpful.

There are three types of timer objects: manual-reset, synchronisation and periodic; and there are four functions for handling the timer objects: CreateWaitableTimer, SetWaitableTimer, CancelWaitableTimer and CloseHandle (there is a fifth, OpenWaitableTimer but that is unlikely to useful to many people). There are also a set of functions required for notification of when a timer expires: WaitForSingleObject, MsgWaitForSingleObject, WaitForMultipleObjects and MsgWaitForMultipleObjects being the most useful.

The usual method for using these timers is:

```
CreateWaitableTimer (...)
SetWaitableTimer (...)
WaitForSingleObject (...)
CloseHandle (...)
```

Compare this to SetTimer - the only way to know if a timer has expired is to poll it, either in a loop or with an infinte timeout (i.e. suspend the thread until the timer elapses).

Pros: very flexible, no need to have a message queue.
Cons: hard to use

Answer (score 3):

There are two timer related functions on the Windows system: SetTimer and KillTimer (I know, the names are odd - CreateTimer and DestroyTimer would be more sensible, as in CreateWindow and DestroyWindow, but that is what is available).

SetTimer can function in one of two modes: the timer event can trigger a user defined callback or it can post a message to a window. The format of this function is:

```
timer_id = SetTimer (window, event_id, interval, callback);
```

To use a callback:

```
timer_id = SetTimer (NULL, NULL, interval_in_milliseconds, callback);
```

To get a WM_TIMER message to a window:

```
timer_id = SetTimer (window, event_id, interval_in_milliseconds, NULL);
```

In both cases, the calling thread needs to have a message queue as both variants issue a WM_TIMER message, the default handler calls the callback function.

Depending on the OS you're using the value of interval has upper and lower bounds. [See the API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906.aspx) for more details.

To release the timer after you're finished with it do the following if you provided a window handle:

```
KillTimer (window, event_id); // event_id is important!
```

and if you used a callback:

```
KillTimer (NULL, timer_id);
```

A single window can have many timers associated with it, use a different event_id for each timer. Reusing an event_id stops the first instance of the timer without posting the WM_TIMER message.

Pros: fairly easy to use.
Cons: latency between interval end and processing of WM_TIMER message, resolution is large, requires a message processing loop.

Comment: Also, I think these timers a one-shot only.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, look at the API you are going to use, for example MFC, Qt or GTK; they all have timer classes.

If you're not going to use a GUI API, I personally like boost::timer (www.boost.org)

Answer (score 0):

For high resolution timers, use [queryperformancecounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: The QueryPerformanceCounter function is useful for measuring how long a sequence of code takes to execute. It's not usful when you want a notification when a period of time elapses, that would require a polling loop: do { sleep a bit} while (interval not expired).